# Python: Webscrape to download all datasets from website

Tags: python, web-scraping

I need to download all datasets from this website: https://www.electionreturns.pa.gov/ReportCenter/Reports
(P.S. you will be redirected to another website if you are not searching from US)
This website has a dropdown, based on dropdown you choose, it returns checkboxes. I need to write a program that would access this website choose every possible option from dropdown, check all checkboxes and download datasets that would be returned after a dropdown and checkboxes.

Dropdown looks like this:
[image]
Checkboxes after a selection of one of the dropdown option look like this:
[image]

This is how I started so far:

```
html_text=requests.get('https://www.electionreturns.pa.gov/ReportCenter/Reports').content
soup=BeautifulSoup(html_text,'lxml')
options=soup.find_all('option')
```

The problem here is that if i print options it doesn't return dropdown options. Instead it returns the placeholder:

```
<select class="form-control ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched bg-border-mandatory" name="ddlElections" ng-change="rpt.electionChagned(rpt.SelectedElection)" ng-model="rpt.SelectedElection" ng-options="value as value.ElectionName for value in rpt.electionList" placeholder="Select Election">
<option value="">Select Election</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This may be a job for playwright (https://playwright.dev/python/) where you can remote control a browser to behave like a human.

Comment: @D21 When I go to the site, it redirects me to https://www.vote.pa.gov/Voting-in-PA/Pages/Pennsylvania-Voter-Election-Security-Information.aspx. See [screenshot](https://snipboard.io/Vwjp5N.jpg) of my browser. It is possible that the site is blocking users from the other countries.

Comment: @Jurakin that's true. they redirect to another page if you are not searching from US

Comment: @D21 Do you want to select all possible option from `report type` as well or just only the `election`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used USA vpn to access the site. Icreated script to save all elections from the select and check all checkboxes including district report type. *Only by using requests library.** Make sure you have `Elections` folder in the current working directory created (or change path). `2015 Special Election 5th Senatorial District` have no data, so the file is not downloaded.

Hope my program helps.

```
import requests
import json

def normalize(data: bytes) -> bytes:
    while True:
        try:
            data = json.loads(data)
        except:
            break

    return data

session = requests.session()

page = session.get("https://www.electionreturns.pa.gov/api/Reports/GetElectionList")
page.raise_for_status()

data = normalize(page.content)

count = len(data["Table"])

print(f"Got {count} elections ...")
for index, election in enumerate(data["Table"]):
    election_name = election["ElectionName"]
    election_id = election["Electionid"]
    election_type = election["ElectionType"]

    print(f"{round(index/count*100)}% Processing '{election_name}' ...")

    page = session.get(f"https://www.electionreturns.pa.gov/api/Reports/GetFilterData?electionId={election_id}&electionsubtype={election_type}")
    page.raise_for_status()

    filter_data = normalize(page.content)

    #print(filter_data)

    page = session.get(f"https://www.electionreturns.pa.gov/api/Reports/GetFilterData?electionId={election_id}&electionsubtype={election_type}&reportType=D")
    page.raise_for_status()

    filter_data_districts = normalize(page.content)

    #print(filter_data_districts)

    data = {
        "ElectionID": election_id,
        "ElectionsubType": election_type,
        "OfficeIds": [value["OfficeID"] for value in filter_data["Table"]],
        "RetOfficeIds": [],
        "PartyIds": [value["PartyID"] for value in filter_data["Table1"]],
        "DistrictIds": [value["DistrictID"] for value in filter_data_districts["Table1"]],
        "CandidateIds": [value["CandidateID"] for value in filter_data["Table2"]],
        "CountyIds": [],
        "ReferendumIds": [],
        "ReferendumDetailIds": [],
        "ExportType": "C", # C = CSV; E = Excel; T = Txt; 
        "ReportType": "D", # D = Districts; C = County; S = Statewide;
        "FileName": "UnOfficial"
    }

    # {
    #     "ElectionID": election_id,
    #     "ElectionsubType": election_type,
    #     "OfficeIds": [
    #         13
    #     ],
    #     "RetOfficeIds": [],
    #     "PartyIds": [
    #         3,
    #         4
    #     ],
    #     "DistrictIds": [
    #         104
    #     ],
    #     "CandidateIds": [
    #         21065,
    #         21066
    #     ],
    #     "CountyIds": [],
    #     "ReferendumIds": [],
    #     "ReferendumDetailIds": [],
    #     "ExportType": "C",
    #     "ReportType": "D",
    #     "FileName": "UnOfficial"
    # }

    #print(data)
    
    page = session.post("https://www.electionreturns.pa.gov/api/Reports/GenerateReport",json=data)
    
    if page.ok:
        print(f"Downloading into './Elections/{election_name}.csv'")
        with open(f"./Elections/{election_name}.csv", "wb") as file:
            file.write(page.content)
    else:
        print(f"Error {page.status_code}! {page.content.decode()}")
```

Comment: thank you very much! sorry for late reply